# Replace NA's by corresponding value in pair (2 rows is 1 pair)

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, na

I'm trying to find a loop that replaces `NA`'s by designated values.

Say I have a data frame as follows (I actually have more rows):

```
a<-c(18,NA,12,33,32,14,15,55)
b<-c(18,30,12,33,32,14,15,NA)
c<-c(16,18,17,45,22,10,24,11)
d<-c(16,18,17,42,NA,10,24,11)
data<- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))
names(data)<-rep(1:8)
```

All rows in my data frame are in pairs (`row[1]` and `[2]` are the first pair, `row[3]` and `[4]` are the second and so on).

I wish to replace all `NA`'s by the corresponding value of the pair i.e to replace `NA` in the first pair by 30. Similarly, replace `NA` in the 4th row by 22.

Is there a loop I can carry out to treat each 2 rows as a pair and replace any `NA`s found by its corresponding value in the same pair?

Comment: Do you want to replace `NA` in the second row by `55`?

Comment: note your example does not work -- you need to exchange the 5th and 6th rows.

Comment: Yes i wish to replace NA in the 2nd row by 55 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure -- this does the trick:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    missing <- which(is.na(data[i,]))
    if(i%%2) {
        data[i,missing] <- data[(i+1), missing]
    } else {
        data[i, missing] <- data[(i-1), missing]
    }
}
```

It allows for missing observations in both the top and bottom row of each pair, and where there is a gap it fills in with the observation from the same column location in the other part of the pair.

note there's no error checking, or other nice stuff, so this is pretty raw.

Also, if they are truly pairs of data, there are better means of joining your observations than just sticking them all into a `dataframe`.

Comment: they are truly pairs. all NA's are missing data. 
I got all together in a 3362 rows data frame of 1681 pairs :(

Comment: @YeshnaBharathiBhowon if you have a very large data set, you should look at the vectorised solution by SimonO101 -- as R is slow at loops. My approach is perhaps a little clearer for beginners, but his will be faster if performance matters.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use R's built in vectorisation to find and replace `NA`s by the appropriate value. Seems like you want to replace by the row below when a row is odd numbered and the row above when it is even numbered...

```
# Locate NAs in data
nas <-  which( is.na( data ) , arr.ind = TRUE )
#  row col
#a   1   2
#d   4   5
#b   2   8

#  Where to get replacement value from: below on odd rows and value above on even rows
rows <- nas[,1] %% 2
rows[ rows == 0 ] <- -1
repl <- cbind( ( nas[,1] + rows ) , nas[ ,2] )

#  Do replacement
data[ nas ] <- data[ repl ]
#   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
#a 18 30 12 33 32 14 15 55
#b 18 30 12 33 32 14 15 55
#c 16 18 17 45 22 10 24 11
#d 16 18 17 42 22 10 24 11
```

I'm sure the creation of the replacement locations matrix could be a little cleaner, but this should be fast as it only uses vectorised operations.